# TypeError: f is not a function

Tags: javascript, debugging, recursion, typeerror

I'm learning javascript from eloquentjavascript.net and I'm currently on the last question of http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#p_UL/8si2OX7.

I'm to create an implementation for  Array.prototype.every() and Array.prototype.some(). This is what I've come up with:

```
function every (array, f) {
  if (array.size == 1) return f(array[0]);
   return ((f(array[0])) && (every(array.slice(1))));
}

function some (array, f) {
  if (array.size == 1) return f(array[0]);
  return ((f(array[0])) || (every(array.slice(1))));
}

console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
// → false
console.log(some([NaN, 3, 4], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(some([2, 3, 4], isNaN));
// → false
```

When I run my code, I get

```
TypeError: f is not a function (line 18 in function every) 
 called from line 18 in function every
 called from line 26
```

I'm pretty sure f is a function. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: These are both more complicated and more memory-churning than the simple solution. Also fairly sure they can't be tail-optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing `f` into `every` when you recurse:

```
function every (array, f) {
  if (array.size == 1) return f(array[0]);
   return ((f(array[0])) && (every(array.slice(1), f)));
// ----------------------------------------------^^^
}
```

Also note you're calling `every`, not `some`, from `some` (and `some` has the same problem with `f`).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two issues - 
1. You are not passing  "f" in all calls.
2. Size is not the array's function.

Try below code -

```
function every (array, f) {
  if (array.length == 1) return f(array[0]);
   return ((f(array[0])) && (every(array.slice(1),f)));
}

function some (array, f) {
  if (array.length == 1) return f(array[0]);
  return ((f(array[0])) || (every(array.slice(1),f)));
}

console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
// → false
console.log(some([NaN, 3, 4], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(some([2, 3, 4], isNaN));
// → false
```

Comment: What if array is undefined or array.length===0?

Comment: Ah, I missed their using `size` rather than `length`. :-)